# ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Tags: solidity

Hello i am trying to verify my test token on binance testnet and getting error about importing erc20 .

```
 --> myc:4:1:
  |
4 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestC is ERC20{
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("TestC", "ALPH") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
    
}
```

remix compiler compiles with no errors or warnings at all . but when y try to verify source code on bncscan it returns this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic issue when verifying source code from block explorer's UI.
Copy contents from "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"; create new file named ERC20.sol; paste copied code in this file and change your import statement to
`import ./ERC20.sol;`

Comment: or just use flattener plugin to make one file and verify then